# I have two tables, how can I group one tables by a column in the other, and then sort the groupings by size?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this:

```
table name: uno
str_id | title
----------
 "a1"  | "hi"
 "b2"  | "bye"
 "c3"  | "etc."

table name: dos
str_id | other_col_name
-------------------------
   "b2"  |  1
   "b2"  |  5
   "a1"  |  6
   "b2"  |  7
```

I would like my query to look at the values in `uno.str_id` and then figure out an ordering of str_ids that have the most values in `dos.str_id`. I think I will need to join them on str_id and then order by count, but I am unsure how to do this in SQL syntax. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.str_id FROM uno u
INNER JOIN dos d ON d.str_id = u.str_id
GROUP BY u.str_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

**EDIT**

the possible WHERE part must be put after the JOIN part (SQL syntax).

You MUST use aliases (or complete table name) if you're querying on two tables with "same-named" fields, if you do anything with these common fields. In that query, Table uno is aliased as "u" and table dos is aliased as "d". This mean, if you have a field title in uno and in dos, you have to write u.title to query on uno.title

version with aliases :

```
SELECT u.str_id FROM uno u
INNER JOIN dos d ON d.str_id = u.str_id
GROUP BY u.str_id
WHERE u.title = 'bla blabla'
AND d.title IN ('asdf', 'ersg')
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

version without aliases (complete table name to avoid confusion for DBMS)

```
SELECT uno.str_id FROM uno 
INNER JOIN dos  ON dos.str_id = unon.str_id
GROUP BY uno.str_id
WHERE uno.title = 'bla bla bla'
AND dos.title IN ('asdf', 'ersg')
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: I am new to SQL. How is the value of `d` inferred in `INNER JOIN dos ON d.str_id = u.str_id`?

Comment: Typo, sorry, I edited. By the way, this will give you : "b2" (cause it's present 3 times) then "a1". Do you wanna see c3 even if it's not present in table dos ? And do you really want a count, or a sum of "other_col_name" values ?

Comment: I just want "b2" and "a1" Thanks. It will take a while to kick off this query, but I'll accept your answer when I can.

Comment: I have one more question, sorry. Let's say I want a condition on which items I select from uno before the join. For instance, `WHERE title = "hi"`. Where would this go?

Comment: after the JOIN, before the GROUP BY.

Comment: Does it go after join even if both tables have a column named title, and I would specifically like u.title = "title"? Do you think you could edit your response to show how this would be used? I'm sorry for all the follow up questions.

Comment: @Max Here you are, my dear ;)